# Receiving unregistered task of type Error

Tags: django, celery

Im getting the error  `[2021-03-27 18:36:43,996: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'orders.tasks.order_created'. The message has been ignored and discarded.` This error only occurs with `celery multi start w1 -A speedrealm -l DEBUG`. My goal is that the task is going to run in the back grtound. I've tired running in different dirs (top-=level and app_dir), and I have also tried commenting/uncommenting `CELERY_IMPORTS`. Im not sure if this is needed but here is the conf.d also. Here all the associated system files.

```
performancerealm.com
|---orders
|    | __init__.py
|    |-tasks.py
|    |-views.py
|
|---speedrealm
|    |- __init__.py
|    |- celery.py
|    |- settings.py 
|
|---manage.py
|--- # other apps
```

**orders.py**

```
from celery import shared_task 
from django.core.mail import send_mail 
from .models import Order 

@shared_task 
def order_created(order_id):
    pass
```

**speedrealm.**init**.py**

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__=("celery_app",)
```

**speedrealm/celery.py**

```
import os 
from celery import Celery 
from django.conf import settings 

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'speedrealm.settings')

app = Celery('speedrealm')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**speedrealm.settings.py**

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
CELERY_BIN="/home/bulofants/.local/share/virtualenvs/performancerealm.com-8nBM01mn/bin"

CELERY_APP="speedrealm"
CELERYD_CHIR="/home/bulofants/performancerealm.com"
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

CELERYD_USER="bulofants"
CELERYD_GROUP="bulofants"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
CELERY_IMPORTS = [
    'orders.tasks'
]
CELERY_TIMEZONE='US/Eastern'
```

.
**/etc/systemd/system/celery.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service 
After=network.target 

[Service]
Type=forking
User=bulofants

EnvironmentFile=/home/bulofants/sites/performancerealm.com 
WorkingDirectory=/home/bulofants/sites/performancerealm.com 
ExecStart=/home/bulofants/.local/share/virtualenvs/performancerealm.com-8nBM01mn/bin/celery  multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}
ExecStop=/home/bulofants/.local/share/virtualenvs/performancerealm.com-8nBM01mn/bin/celery ${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}
ExecReload=/home/bulofants/.local/share/virtualenvs/performancerealm.com-8nBM01mn/bin/celery  ${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**orders.views.py**

```
.tasks import order_created

order_created.delay()
```

This will ONLY work if I run `celery -A speedrealm worker -l INFO` in the top-level. The program runs perfectly. The ony reason i say top-level is becuase some anwers were saying running celery command in the file/app containing the tasks. If I do so, no module found with `orders` or `speedrealm` or the Improperly Configured Error is returned and other imports that are in the module are then labeled as not defined, ie settings (from django.conf import settings). Im using an Linux Server, Ubuntu 16.04. I am manually start /restarting these workers and always using the daemon-reload command.

Answer (score 0):

**init**.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ["celery_app"]
```

celery.py

```
import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourapp.settings")

app = Celery("yourapp")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

in settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://localhost"  # or Redis instead of RabbitMQ
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["json"]
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {"visibility_timeout": 3600}
```

in tasks.py

```
from yourapp.celery import app

@app.task()
def my_task(parameters):
    do_something()
```

in Linux
/etc/conf.d/celery

```
# single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or you could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/usr/your_celery_path/bin/celery"

CELERY_APP="yourapp"

CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=2"  # or your own concurrency

CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="ERROR"  # or your own logging level
```

/etc/systemd/system/celery.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=celery-user
Group=your_webserver_group
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
WorkingDirectory=/your_django_app_root_path/

ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
    -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \-logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} \
    --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
    --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
    -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
    --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Create the celery-user (or other username of your choice) and add this user to the webserver group. Set permissions for the group to access Django app folders.

Create PID and Log folders and give Celery permissions to them.

```
sudo useradd -r celery-user -s /sbin/nologin
sudo usermod -a -G your_webserver_group celery-user

mkdir /var/log/celery
chown -R celery-user:your_webserver_group /var/log/celery

mkdir /var/run/celery
chown -R celery-user:your_webserver_group /var/run/celery

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable celery.service
sudo systemctl start celery.service
```

Comment: I've given the full shebang to run Celery as a service, which is what you should do for production use. If it doesn't work then try a newer version of Ubuntu. I've had better experience with RabbitMQ than with Redis on Ubuntu, for some reason Celery keeps looking for RabbitMQ even if settings.py points to a Redis endpoint.

Comment: Yeah I’m using RabbitMq. Would any of this explain why multi is causing an error? Using a single worker, celery runs fine. I’ve read that people use supervisor, but I’m using Python3.8 which doesn’t seem to play too nicely with Supervisor in Ubuntu. Sorry for not specifying this sooner. I will test this implementation that you have left

Comment: I'm using this setup w/o Supervisor and it works well.

Comment: thanks for your help. I finally re-tackled this. After one full day of learning how to read the RabbitMq terminal and learning Celery, I decided to create another virtual env. I hard coded all the values and got it to work. Ill go back and see what might have been the issue. I remove the "options" and  "PID" arg also, since it seems like there was an argument not transfering over from the environment file. I also created a new virtualenv instead of using pipenv. Thanks again for your help.